# Drawing on Canvas programatically makes the image move

Tags: android, canvas

I'm doing an app where I load an image into an ImageView and after that I draw multiple 50x50 pixels squares on the ImageView. Here's what I'm talking about :

[image]

[image]

The code that I use to make the squares is this one :

```
    private void splitImage() {


    Bitmap aux = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(aux);
    imgView.draw(c);

    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        for (int xCoord = 0; xCoord < width; xCoord += 50) {

            c.drawLine(xCoord, 0, xCoord, height, p);

        }

    for (int yCoord = 0; yCoord < height; yCoord+=50){

        c.drawLine(0, yCoord, width, yCoord, p);

    }

    imgView.setImageResource(0);

    imgView.setImageBitmap(aux);

}
```

Did you see this problem before ?

Comment: what is `width` and `height` ? the size of original `Bitmap`? if so, instead of `imgView.draw(c);` use `c.drawBitmap`

Comment: @pskink width and height are the dimensions in pixels of the image that is being shown in the ImageView. I'll try with drawBitmap. Thanks !

Comment: Seems like if I use c.drawBitmap it doesn't show anything

Comment: I solved it eventually. Thank you ! I posted an answer with what you told me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @pskink the problem was solved. Instead of imgView.draw(c) I used c.drawBitmap(bm, 0, 0, p);